# How to use $or with mongo db aggregation

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, aggregation-framework

I am using aggregation pipeline with `$match`,`$project` and `$geonear` pipeline operators.

In each of collection I have field for week days like:

1. `repeat_every_monday =true`,
2. `repeat_every_tuesday=true`,

Same sequence for all week days.

Now if today is tuesday then I have to put `$or` condition in my pipeline operator to fetch all that record also with the previous data, which are marked as `repeat_every_tuesday=true`,

I would like to express a conditional operation like

```
if (name=="pankaj" and "test"=="false" || "test"==true)
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
db.test.aggregate([
     {'$match':{"name":"pankaj","test":false,}},
     {'$project':{_id:1‌​,name:1,test:1,sir:1}}
]).pretty()
```

where i have to put `$or`?

```
I have test collection and data is as below:
     db.test.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e79492f286d94702cf4e31"),
    "name" : "pankaj",
    "test" : true,
    "sir" : "cheema"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e7abb3f286d94702cf4e32"),
    "name" : "pankaj",
    "test" : false,
    "sir" : "cheema"
}


I want a aggregate query with $match which should  give me result where     name is =pankaj and test is either true or false .
    For example in sql :
    Select * from test where name=pankaj or test=false or test =true.
```

Comment: Ok, so what exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to use $or with my aggregation .

Comment: db.test.aggregate([{'$match':{"name":"pankaj","test":false,}},{'$project':{_id:1,name:1,test:1,sir:1}}]).pretty()     where i have to put $or

Comment: Still not sure what exactly you want to do. Do you want to express this condition? `(name == "pankaj" and "test" == false ) || repeat_every_tuesday == true`?

Comment: Hi Phillipp thanks for your prompt response , actually I want something like (name=="pankaj" and "test"=="false" || "test"==true) means the result should consist all record where name=pankaj and test is either true or false Thanks

Comment: OK but I am confused why you went into that long introduction about weekly repetitions when it apparently hasn't got anything to do with your actual problem.

Comment: My actual problem is that how to use $or with aggregate in pipeline. can you provide me any sample query for this .Repeat weekly on the basis of days is my business logic ,but till now am not able to use simple $or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Like this

```
db.articles.aggregate( [
  { $match: { $or: [ {"$and":["name":"pankaj","test":"false"]}, 
  {"test":"true"}]}},

] );
```

Comment: Your `$and` is redundant. You can just pass an object with multiple fields and MongoDB will and-relate them automatically. You only need `$and` in a few rare corner-cases. Namely when you need to use another operator multiple times with different values.

Comment: This is generating syntax error somewhere .   2016-03-15T15:37:44.046+0530 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: db.test.aggregate([ { $match: { $or: [ {"$and":[{"name":"pankaj"},{"test":"false"}]},{"test":"true"}]}}])